# Call function for each variadic argument with FastDelegate

Tags: c++11, delegates, variadic-functions

Using [FastDelegate](http://www.codeproject.com/cpp/FastDelegate.asp) library, is it possible to create a delegate able to call the desired function for each argument of a parameter pack from the caller? As opposed to calling the function once with all arguments. Also supporting the function being object-based.

In other words, an option to replace this kind of approach:

```
template<typename F, typename... T>
void ForEachArgument(F function, T&&... args)
{
    for (auto& arg : { args... })
    {
        function(arg);
    }
}

class CNetworkMenu
{
    void RemoveItemByAction(int);

    template<typename... T>
    void RemoveItemsByActions(T... args)
    {
        ForEachArgument([&](int arg)
        {
            RemoveItemByAction(arg);
        }, args...);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code in your example?

Comment: Nothing, other than if the same was possible with FastDelegate I could avoid having that custom function (ForEachArgument) and also another potential variant for 'thiscalls' when I'd need. Looking for DRY'ing/reusability basically.

Comment: `ForEachArgument` looks DRY and reusable to me. I think it's a neat solution. Sorry I don't know anything better!

Comment: FastDelegate does not seem to provide something to avoid writing `ForEachArgument`. FastDelegate would rather replace your use of a lambda, but I don't know how it works. However I see a way to optimize `ForEachArguement` slightly.

Comment: @VictorPaléologue How could it be optimized?

Answer (score 1):

`FastDelegate` does not seem to provide something to avoid writing `ForEachArgument`. `FastDelegate` would rather replace your use of a lambda, but I don't know how it works.

However, you could optimize `ForEachArguement`, by making sure you do not copy arguments. Here, `RemoveItemsByActions(T... args)` requires taking the ownership to the arguments (aka *by value*), then moves them down to `ForEachArgument`'s `{ args... }`. The `for` loop refers to these args by reference (`auto& arg`) and passes them to your lambda, which takes the `arg` by value. If `arg` was not an `int`, it would trigger an unneeded copy.

To avoid this and give as much room to the compiler as possible to optimize the work, I would try to unpack the values using the templates, and make sure that [universal references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) are used all across. Here is the trick:

```cpp
template<typename F, typename T>
void for_each_any(F&& function, T&& next_arg)
{
    function(next_arg);
}

template<typename F, typename T, typename... U>
void for_each_any(F&& function, T&& next_arg, U&&... args)
{
    function(next_arg);
    for_each_any(std::forward<F>(function), std::forward<U>(args)...);
}
```

See it [in action here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgCspAAOqAqETgwe3r56KWmOAiFhkSwxcdJ2mA4ZQgRMxARZPn4BldUCtfUERRHRsQm2dQ1NOVyDXT0lZSCSAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMocjeWADUJutuTgoExJisB9gmGgCCG1s7mPuHXo60hACel9d3twSYLCSBn%2BBzcBA%2BSUYrCeADFSLtwZDmGxdgAVb63ABuqDw6F2/GIAH1zsgEITDB8IDDzAA2Wn4rwMdoMeHosx09m7MKqAjk4jAWY/EwAdist12EoZTIKDAg3N59QFBzFd2FABEhX8AUCmCDDoioSi4QiIYanqj4QbkZgAHR23ZyDE3bG4/EkYlMUnkhiU6ns%2BlURnM1m0%2BnyvnAeGO/3su023aKhSC24ilWSqXMuWYHkRwXrNOSgker0UiAndAgEAEgDu9XQoOp62w1CDMvmu3LlZrddBjqbEETszjeZVIo1KduAHpJ2jTbsPotiLs0HsELFMPCSLtaKgmHjDLts6wgbafqECLsWExQhBZvtRT900WSWTSyZ4lZ4mqB69UKHOYqgoPuK6aSp2KCLBeoKgh2BAVlWJC1sQ9aHFg2wGgO/J5s2gHPG4MHga4tDKo%2BkpjvC5hmIYCjVrElEUWYZh4Ao9G7JIZgjqREpnAQSwMLsGgkSm6o/Bw8y0Jw8S8H4HBaKQqCcPhljWB2i4rPsZjrDwpAEJoYnzAA1iA6zrDaJnmRZlk0vonCSNJenyZwvAKCAGg6Xp8xwLASBoICdCxOQlC%2BUk/lxMAXCMXwdD/MQLkQFEDlRKE9QfJw2m%2BWwggAPIMLQqWybwWBXkY4gFaQ%2BBnNUmKYC5ZXZlUryrNp56YBJZXvFExApR4WAOaceAsGlYl8AYwAKAAangmDVllSJDTIggiGI7BSAt8hKGoDm6GMBhGCg1jWPoeBRC5kDzKgSQyrVzmtVUMouAw7ieM0ejBKEvSlP0Yx5OkAgjH432pL9DCTH0cRjG0MqdMMz2jLYt3MtD3TvVMX3jDD2QA%2BjyPFGDEjzAoakrTpZxNcNbVSaQMlyQpHCqAAHDSAC0NKSLswDIMguwRTaZi7BASlWJY8K4IQW4bGMuweH59BLhLsy8LpBWzPMa57v0t6kEZJlmZZesmdZbV2VTDm085rnucrpBeYgID1cgv5kBQmFjcohitUICCoNWMnpagMu6hkbthLQnve9TvDBaFIDhZFUey1lrxhz7Dn2zc/LXYEqhVLU%2BAybw/CLaI4irYX60qOoZXbfohjGAdwsdadmsXVdTkLEsKx6OWoTBx7Xsp9wiuk/N1ZdUkQ3iZJ9llbT2DZw7RBLgzzOs%2BznPc2YvP84Lh27KLi8aVpCuW1oKta8Zpn6/rNkcMbEeORw5tuUrp%2BTxwZjTzTbcv/ppDVbFGQZhAA%3D). I have put [your solution here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:28,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:28,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:28,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:28,startLineNumber:17),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+F,+typename...+T%3E%0Avoid+ForEachArgument(F+function,+T%26%26...+args)%0A%7B%0A++++for+(auto%26+arg+:+%7B+args...+%7D)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++function(arg)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A//+Type+your+code+here,+or+load+an+example.%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++ForEachArgument(%5B%5D(auto%26%26+arg)%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+std::forward%3Cdecltype(arg)%3E(arg)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D,+%22answer%22,+%22is%22,+%2242%22)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).
Then I [benchmarked them together here](https://quick-bench.com/q/ayIxhU_shcbgfn34B780eN1NW0Y), and it shows that my proposed solution is slightly better. However there is a trade-off: my solution results in a slightly larger binary, since it uses more templates, and it compiles more slowly.